# Network service can't access network share under local system account

Tags: windows, service

Am running an application as a windows service but when i trying to run it under local system account my service is not able to access network share .but when i run it under a valid user account my service able to acees network share .. but o would like to run it under local system account ??

nd i can n't set full control for everyone on that network share and am on Windows NT machine

Comment: Go to [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco/510225#510225)

Answer (score 1):

You shared drive is mapped to a user account with AD domain access.  The network service account has no such access on the other server.  Use a AD domain ID to map the shared drive or run the service under a user account.

Comment: You don't have to use a user account but you will have to use user credentials to map the drive.