# How to Run PHP on IIS7.5 Express?

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-express, mysql5, php-5.2, windows-xp-sp3

I have Win XP SP3 and have installed IIS7.5 Express and want to run PHP on it.

I am able to run simple HTML code on the server, I am able to start and stop the server by running iisservices.exe, but I am not able to run php scripts on it.

If I have the following PHP file:

```
<? php 
echo "hello world";
?>
<html>HI</html>
```

The output is `HI` but the PHP script doesn't run.

I have followed the steps described in this article to install PHP:

> http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/724/install-and-configure-php/

But can't proceed from step 10 onwards because IIS Express doesn't have an IIS Management Console MMC snap-in.

How do I configure IIS Express to run PHP?

Answer (score 38):

Assuming you've carried out steps 1 - 9 in [the article you linked to](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/724/install-and-configure-php/) and have your PHP files extracted to `c:\php` then complete the following steps using a `cmd.exe` command prompt:

Firstly we need to configure IIS Express and setup a handler for PHP

```
cd "\Program Files\IIS Express"

appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',arguments='',maxInstances='4',idleTimeout='300',activityTimeout='30',requestTimeout='90',queueLength='1000',instanceMaxRequests='200',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False',rapidFailsPerMinute='10']" /commit:apphost

appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP-FastCGI',path='*.php',modules='FastCgiModule',verb='*', scriptProcessor='c:\php\php-cgi.exe']" /commit:apphost
```

Assuming your PHP website resides in `c:\MyPHPWeb` we create a site in IIS Express that listens on `http://localhost:32701`:

```
appcmd add site /name:"MyPHPApp" /bindings:http/*:32701: /physicalPath:"c:\MyPHPWeb"
```

Next start the site:

```
iisexpress.exe /site:MyPHPApp
```

And finally browse to your PHP page:

```
http://localhost:32701/test.php
```

Comment: I wish I could mark this as the answer but it is not my question...best I could do was mark it as useful. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying this on my mac book with vmware fusion and I had to stop the shared folder in order for this to work

Comment: For anybody setting this up on Windows(7 for me) and it's saying you don't have permission to start the site, make sure you run command prompt as administrator.

Comment: I'm running on Win10 Creators Edition and this was exactly the config I needed (other than replacing the `php-cgi.exe` location with `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe`.  +1 also on the note to run IISExpress as an Administrator.

Answer (score 4):

**Option-1: (From command line)**

1. Go to IIS Express installation folder (%programfiles%\iis express)
2. Run following two commands

```cmd
appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath=**'c:{php_installation-folder}\php-cgi.exe'**] 

appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='.php',verb='',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='c:{php_installation-folder}\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Unspecified']
```

**Option-2: (Using UI)**

1. Install WebMatrix  (from http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)
2. Start WebMatrix and choose 'Site From Folder' option  and select your php file folder and click OK
3. In the WebMatrix left pan select Settings (bottom of the left pan select 'Site' and on the top of the left pan select 'Settings')
4. In the settings tab, check the PHP check box, this would install PHP and configure for you.
5. Click 'Restart' button in WebMatrix to restart IIS Express
6. In WebMatrix left pan bottom select 'Files' and on the top of the left pan (tree view), you should see your php page and now right click on this page node and select 'Launch in Browser'

Answer (score -4):

Download php installer.

It should let you choose what type of server, so choose IIS and then it should work from there.

Comment: What? im not asking for **any** of your info. I am just telling you how to make your code work...