# run php site on iis express

Tags: php, iis-express

I've been trying to run a simple hello world php site from iis express, following this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086364/744610

but i keep getting an error 500 from the iis, and in the cmd i can see a 404 error regarding a fav icon.

detailed informaion from the 500 error

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP-FastCGI
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:32701/index.php
Physical Path      c:\myphpsite\index.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\PHPTEST
```

i double checked at the physical path is indeed correct.

the cmd:

```
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:32701/index.php
Request ended: http://localhost:32701/index.php with HTTP status 500.0
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:32701/favicon.ico
Request ended: http://localhost:32701/favicon.ico with HTTP status 404.0
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:32701/index.php
Request ended: http://localhost:32701/index.php with HTTP status 500.0
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:32701/favicon.ico
Request ended: http://localhost:32701/favicon.ico with HTTP status 404.0
```

i tried f5'ing a couple of times, hence the repetitions.

my index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply use Web Matrix with PHP.