# IIS Express: Cannot read application.config file

Tags: php, iis, iis-express

As I have seen on: [How to Run PHP on IIS7.5 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080374/how-to-run-php-on-iis7-5-express#7086364)

I try to run:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',arguments='',maxInstances='4',idleTimeout='300',activityTimeout='30',requestTimeout='90',queueLength='1000',instanceMaxRequests='200',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False',rapidFailsPerMinute='10']" /commit:apphost
```

But I get the following error:

[image: CMD Console application error]

Do you fellows have an idea how to solve this. I already have cd into `C:\Program Files\IIS Express` and my php in install in `C:\php`.

Comment: Are you using IIS 10 Express?

Comment: Yes I am running IIS express 10

Comment: Depending on how to get IIS 10 Express installed, the error can be expected. Does the file mentioning in the error message exist on your machine? Anyway you can use Jexus Manager (IIS Manager for IIS Express) to add PHP support manually, http://jexusmanager.com .