# How many Types of Users in ASP.NET/IIS(or Cassini or IIS Express) and thier actual Role?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, cassini

I am asking about the account of the user which run the ASP.NET/IIS (or Cassini or IIS Express) application. I am asking about the defaults. There is very much confusion out there. Googling shows me lot of types of users, for example,

- my-computer-name\myname user,
- IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4 user,
- IIS_WPG,
- IIS_IUSRS user,
- Network service user,
- AspNet user,
- IUSR_MachineName user,
- IIS_IUSRS user,
- IUSR user,
- IIS_WPG user,
- IWAM_computername user,
- IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool user.

These are quite confusing.

Comment: There are some excellent tips at here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one this is different based on the version of Windows that you are running. And second, you are asking about 3 different servers. So that is probably what is making it confusing.

### Development servers

First, the easiest one: Cassini. This server runs under the same account and with the same privileges as the Visual Studio instance that it's started from. Usually, this is just your own Windows account.

IIS Express uses the exact same code-base as IIS, but it will run under your own Windows account as well, the same account that started Visual Studio (or Web Matrix for that matter).

### IIS 6.0

Now for IIS proper. Here you may find many accounts. First of all, the 'old' IIS 6.0 that you will still find on Windows Server 2003 machines would use the following accounts:

- **Network Service** (*default and recommended worker processes identity for application pools in IIS 6.0 and above*)
- **Local Service** (*pretty limited access*)
- **Local System** (*used for the worker process when running in 'IIS 5.0 isolation mode', member of Administrators and has full access*)
- **IIS_WPG** (*short for Worker Process Group, not an account, but a group, worker process identities should be member of this group, to get minimal required permissions*)
- **IUSR_ComputerName** (*not used for a worker process, but rather to map anonymous visitors to a Windows account*)
- **IWAM_{ComputerName}** (*for IIS 5.0 isolation mode, you'd typically use application pools for isolation nowadays*)
- **ASPNET** (*also for IIS 5.0 isolation mode, it looks like **the** ASP.NET account, but in most cases it isn't*)

(This list is based on the TechNet article [IIS and Built-in Accounts (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true).)

### IIS 7 and above

For IIS 7, some of these listed above are no longer relevant, and some are replaced. Since these accounts are built-in to Windows, they have the same SSID everywhere, which may come in handy now and then.

If you upgraded a server from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008, of if you install IIS 6.0 compatibility features or older IIS components, you *may* have the old *and* the new accounts on one machine.

- **IUSR** (*replaces IUSR_{ComputerName}, so used to map anonymous users by default*)
- **IIS_IUSRS** (*replaces the IIS_WPG group, and so is not an account but rather a group*)

(This is based on the article [Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis).)

### AppPool identities (since IIS 7.0)

This list is now almost complete, but we still need to understand a special type of account: the 'dynamic' AppPool identities. These are not actual accounts on the machine like the others, e.g. you can't find them listed as users in Windows. But they are virtual accounts created on the fly for the application pools, if you choose the ApplicationPoolIdentity option.

If you need to give such an account access privileges to a file or folder, you can still search for the account by typing: **IIS AppPool{DefaultAppPool}** (replace {DefaultAppPool} with the name of the application pool that you created).

(You can read more about this in [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) on iis.net.)

When you install .NET 4.0, then IIS adds a new application pool to be able to run new .NET 4.0 web applications alongside the existing .NET 2.0 web applications. The installer gives this application pool the name ASP.NET v4.0, and uses the option ApplicationPoolIdentity. Hence a dynamic account is created for this new application pool, whether you use it or not.

Comment: One small thing, in which account(by default) my ASP.NET application code runs in IIS 6, 7, 7.5, Cassini and IIS Express. Sometimes, I need to connect SQL Server and sometimes I need to access file system. Is both uses the same account?

Answer (score 3):

Cassini runs under account that started VS. So default would be currently logged windows user, runas will run under specific user account.

Application on IIS runs using application pool. Here is snipp from default site:

[image]

Every Application pool can be configured using Advanced settings:

[image]

I should also point out possible impersonation, where context runs under impersonated user. This user can be provided by IIS or using code. Here is sample how to configure IIS impersonation (Authentication tab for specific app):

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I asked about lot of users. What about the others?

Comment: It is not possible to map all this users to one answer. Just for a sample AspNet user even doesn't exists any more in specific environments... So lets put it this way. It's more important to understand how security on IIS works, because you can use any of this users in specific situation and not all of them at the same time. This is also the reason why there are soo many answers confusing people.

Comment: For IIS buildin accounts there is one nice article http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis