# Can't delete a file in C# - unauthorized access exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In my ASP.Net web application, I have loaded one image on the HTML 5 canvas and allow the user to draw some graphics (rectangle box) over the images. Once the user has finished their drawings on the image I have to save the image back to the server with the same name at same location.

I am using `AJAX` to transmit the image data to the server. This part is done successfully.
In my server code, first I am trying to delete a file and then create a new file with the same name at same location.

So, When I am deleting the file, it is raising `UnAuthorizedAccessException is handled by user code Access to the path 'D:\vs-2010projects\delete_sample\delete_sample\myimages\page_1.png' is denied.`

Here is my Server Side C# Code...

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
    if(File.Exists("D:\\vs-2010projects\\delete_sample\\delete_sample\\myimages\\page_1.png"))
    {
        File.Delete("D:\\vs-2010projects\\delete_sample\\delete_sample\\myimages\\page_1.png");
    }

    FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\vs-2010projects\\delete_sample\\delete_sample\\myimages\\page_1.png", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(data);
    bw.Close();
}//UploadImage
```

Is there any way to delete a file?

Please guide me out of this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should pack your stream statements into `using` clause that will automatically handle dispose action (even in case of exception) - it will save you a lot of time during debugging strange issues coming from not-closed streams

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(...)) 
{
  using(var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)
  {
       bw.Write(data);
  }
}
```

Now the exception often comes because your current process does not have access rights for the file (can't delete file) - to solve it

- add full permissions for your user

You can do this by finding the file in the Windows Explorer , checking its properties and under security tab you will find specific permissions.

For example if you host your page on IIS then it is identified as application pool identity which is either IIS_IUSRS or NETWORK SERVICE and those parties are usually not trusted (or not enough trusted to be able to delete file0

Comment: I added your code and also my image folder has full permission also.I am using iis 5 and windows xp.But still the same error persist

Comment: which users have full access to this folder ?

Comment: I am using windows xp sp2.so it doesn't show me user's information.Generally i marked full control in the web sharing option available when right click the folder(under sharing and security).how can i see?

Comment: Right click on the folder in explorer -> Properties -> Security -> Inside "Group or user names" you have listed all users and when you click on them the appropriate access rights will be presented below

Comment: so how about doing it from command line ? http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-xp/setting-permissions-from-command-prompt.html

Comment: :am trying to set full control for IIS_IUSRS then it says "No mapping between account names and security ID was done". But for NETWORKSERVICE AND SARAVANAN-\ASPNET USERS i have set full control...but there is no positive result

Comment: IIS_IUSRS also exists in context of your computer name so it more like comp_name/IIS_IUSRS , or you can change identity of app pool hosting the web site to network service

Answer (score 1):

I presume, it has something to do with privilege. When a user tries to connect to your Web site, IIS assigns the connection to the IUSER_ComputerName account, which belongs to the Guests group. This group has security restrictions. Try to elevate access of IUSER_ComputerName.
[More can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ).