# Microsoft.office.interop.excel error HRResult 0x800A03EC while saving workbook as Saveas

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Getting below error while saving Workbook as .saveas()
I am using Microsoft.office.interop.excel

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)

Comment: Found something similar to your issue in here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106632/microsoft-office-interop-excel-workbook-saveas-exception-0x800a03ec/41907859". Please have a look and see if it is helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AviS Thanks, my issue is resolved using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106632/microsoft-office-interop-excel-workbook-saveas-exception-0x800a03ec/41907859