# asp.net user group missing iis 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I had a problem running an ASP.NET application (application Pool v4.0) on windows server 2008 IIS 7.5.
I figured out that it's a permissions problem, but I couldn't find ASP.NET user group, so I granted NETWORK SERVICE and still it didn't work until I granted IIS_USERS permission to read/write and modify then it worked.

Why I can't find ASP.NET user group? and how can I add it if possible?

Comment: are you setting your scope for local computer, NOT the domain? Set the proper scope and type in IIS AppPool\ASP .NET v4.0

Comment: type it in verbatim, or the beginning part and hit check names and it should resolve it for you.

Comment: I've tried this already and It didn't work, check names didn't find it.

Comment: try icacls c:\wwwroot\mysite /grant "IIS AppPool\ASP.NET v4.0":(CI)(OI)(M) from elevated command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you come to apply file and folder permissions you grant the Application Pool identity whatever rights are required. For example if you are granting the application pool identity for the `ASP.NET v4.0` pool permissions then you can either do this via Explorer:

[image]

Click the "Check Names" button:

[image]

Or you can do this using the `ICACLS.EXE` utility:

```
icacls c:\wwwroot\mysite /grant "IIS AppPool\ASP.NET v4.0":(CI)(OI)(M)
```

This is taken mostly from [What are all the user accounts for IIS/ASP.NET and how do they differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ), so look at that for the full answer, but this section is pertinent to you.

Comment: Thanks it worked using the command line, but it's bit strange that it didn't work using the Explorer, perhaps you might know why?

Comment: That is quite odd. I think the Check Names box is very very meticulous, All the parameters have to be verbatim like it is above. Glad it worked though with the command line. When in doubt, command line is a good fallback. You can do nearly every IIS Manager function from command line.