# Multiple Application Pools running as Network Service

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, network-service

I have four different Application Pools, each one for a different web site, all running as `Network Service`.

Is this a normal configuration to have?

Can it cause problems between the different applications?

Comment: Is each site running as Application Pool Identity, or have you specified a unique anonymous account for each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configured each site's Anonymous Authentication to use "Application Pool Identity" then requests will run as the `Network service` account.

If this isn't a shared server, i.e. you're not allowing your customers or users to upload content or deploy ASP.NET applications, and you and your team are the sole deployers/mamagers then this isn't a terrible thing to do.

That said, if one site becomes compromised then it will be possible to attackers to compromise the other sites. If the `Network Service` account only has read access then the attack would be limited to data theft, otherwise they'll be able to do much more damage.

Unless you have a very good reason to, it is always a good idea to configure your application pools to run as `Application Pool Identity`. IIS will synthesise an account for you when the application pool is running. You should configure your public facing www folders to give appropriate permissions to an account known as `IIS AppPool\[POOL_NAME]` where `[POOL_NAME]` is the name of the application pool for the site.

You may wish to have a read of one of my previous answers related to this to help you understand this mechanism:

> [What are all the user accounts for IIS/ASP.NET and how do they differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ/5731360#5731360)

And see also:

> [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)