# The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. After deploy MVC5/MVC4 on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I created MVC 5 application from template 2013 VS. If I run it from VS it works.
[image]

I used publish and file deploy to my folder and on IIS I setup new pool: v4, integrated.

[image]

than I created new site using this pool

[image]

I restart IIS but if I run app I get error which is saying that it can't find my Views.

[image]

My folder contains views

[image]

My feautures is set like this:

[image]

I have problem with MVC 4 also but I get page like this.

[image]

In my RouteConfig.cs is this coud:

```
namespace MVC5
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe my feutures are not set good for IIS feautures but I'm lost with this.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the version of .NET the app pool is running

Comment: .NET version for app pool is v4.0.30319 I added new picture - second from top.

Comment: Why your URL is   localhost\mvc5 ?  I think it should be  localhost\new

Comment: check 3. picture path is ok "mvc5" - "new" is just app pool

Comment: the app pool you are showing is called new but on the other screenshot you are using DefaultAppPool

Comment: sorry I added wrong screenshot - I updated it and on picture you can see that pool is set to "new" for site.

Comment: Could you post your route configuration? I believe we can find some clue there.

Comment: On bottom of my post I added route settings but for MVC. Are any route setting for IIS? If yes where can I find it.

Comment: Any other ideas? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finaly I found where was my problem.

Path to my deployed folder was: **"C:\Users\Anton\Downloads\MVC5d"**

But probably IIS is not happy with path located **in folder "Users"**.

I moved it into **"C:\MyProjects\MVC5d"** and everything is working now.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the correct answer should be to give the user `IIS_IUSRS` full permission into your web folder, `mvc5` in your case

`IIS_IUSRS` is the group for IIS Worker Process Accounts

[See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731360/1598095)

[image]

and then sure that the application is using an application pool using the apppoolidentity

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Your steps looks good - I don't see any problem. Try it on different pc or reinstall win.

Comment: Reinstall win? Is that a solution?