# bitmap image saving as blank image

Tags: c#

I need to capture client screen so i reffered http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/capturing-the-screen-image-using-c/

its working fine on local but on server my image is saving as blank image

```
    System.Drawing.Bitmap outputImage  = CaptureScreen.CaptureScreen.GetDesktopImage();
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + "Corporate/testimages/ab1.png");

    outputImage.Save(path);
```

help me out thanks in advance...

Comment: are you working with asp.net?

Comment: yes  and i want to take screen shot using c#

Comment: "client screen" is the beginning of the start of your problems.

Comment: @ Grant Thomas would you suggest me alternative of grabz.it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your application is running by an user without a desktop environment.
There are detected Windows Users for something like Web Applications and this user doesn't have an screen.

You should think about extracting the Screening process in a separate program.

EDIT:
Kratika doesn't want to screen the clients screen, (s)he wants to screen an other website and provide the download link.

Comment: What kind of Link?!?
How to separate a program? Just make a console application.

Comment: @KratikaSharma Sharma Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5731360/4021938

Comment: actually i need to take screen shot of client screen on buttonclick  in my website i cant use console application

Comment: @KratikaSharma This is not possible.
Browsers will not take screenshots for you.
Than you have to write a program, which gets executed on the clients computer. The user has to download this program and execute it.
Your code gets executed on the server and you are getting the screen of the server.

Comment: is there any alternative of grabz.it currently m using it but its to slow and i want to make this process fast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82267/discussion-between-kratika-sharma-and-alex-h).