# The file path is denied when i upload file on iis and mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

when I upload file before publish the project it run right but when publish the project when i upload the file display this error:
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\sites\Khadamatresan\Contents\9164d9fe-d515-47e5-bbf2-95a56219e5c9.png' is denied.

how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please click on below link for better help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you could try to modify the C:\inetpub\sites\Khadamatresan\Contents folder's permission to allow IUSR and IIS/yourapplicationpoolname to read and write file.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Make sure you use the application pool advanced setting's identity is applicationpoolidentity

[image]

2.Right click the C:\inetpub\sites\Khadamatresan\Contents folder and select property.

3.Click the scruity and edit button.

[image]

4.If IUSR and your application pool name doesn't show in the window. I suggest you could
Click the add button and type in IUSR and IIS AppPool\.

[image]

[image]

5.Modify the permission to enable the full control

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder in question and look at the permissions on the folder. My answer is that it only has administrator permissions against it and what you are sending via code doesn't not replicate them permissions.