# Permission issue while accessing report from Report Server into My Applicatoin

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2016

Permission granted to Current User is not sufficient to access the report

I have two server, one is for Report Sever and another one is application server. Both have administrative credential so when i deploy my code and run application and try to access the report i got the permission error

**Error Message:**

> The permissions granted to user 'PNKDC0\WEB01$' are insufficient for
> performing this operation. ---
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
> The permissions granted to user 'PNKDC0\WEB01$' are insufficient for performing this operation.
>
> *Stack Trace:*   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)     at ReportService2010.ReportingService2010.ListChildren(String ItemPath, Boolean Recursive)     at Screening.UI.ReportLauncher.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

For setting permissions within **`SSRS`** you need to run `internet explorer` as `Administrator`             [image]

Open the `report Manager` URL,
Look for **Site Settings** in the top right then click `Security` then **`New Role Assignment`**
[image]
Give your domain\username and select `System Administrator`, click ok
Add other users as necessary
Click home, Folder Settings, then New Role Assignment
[image]
Enter your `domain\username` and select `Content Manager`, click ok close and open `internet explorer` again (non-admin) and check report URL.

> also check your Reporting Services how it configured a and Application Pool for IIS

Comment: if it not work then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986419/apppool-permission-issue-with-accessing-report-server