How to Download Merged PDF Reports from SSRS using ReportViewer in ASP.NET MVC?
I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application and trying to implement a feature that allows users to download merged PDF reports generated from SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). I have a method called DownloadMergedPdf which utilizes the ReportViewer control to render the PDFs.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
public ActionResult DownloadMergedPdf(List<string> Ids, string Title, string reportName)
{
    List<byte[]> fileArray = new List<byte[]>();
    
    if (Ids != null && Ids.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            int totalReports = Ids.Count;
            int currentReportIndex = 0;

            foreach (var id in Ids)
            {
                currentReportIndex++;
                int i = int.Parse(id);
                string SoCt = db.PhieuThu.Where(x => x.Id == i).Select(x =>    x.SoPhieu).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

                // Set the report path and parameters
                reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/DemoReport/" + reportName;
                ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
                parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Id", id, true);
                parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("Title", Title, true);
                reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
                
                // Render the report to PDF
                byte[] pdfBytes = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render(
                    "PDF", 
                    null, 
                    out string mimeType, 
                    out string encoding, 
                    out string fileNameExtension, 
                    out string[] streams, 
                    out Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings
                );

                if (pdfBytes != null && pdfBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileArray.Add(pdfBytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Error rendering report for ID {id}: PDF bytes are null or empty.");
                }
            }

            var mergedBytes = MergePdfBytes(fileArray);
            return File(mergedBytes, "application/pdf", "MergedReport.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error for debugging
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in DownloadMergedPdf: " + ex.Message);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "An error occurred while creating the PDF file: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

Problem: While executing this code on IIS, I encounter the following issues:

The permissions granted to user 'IIS APPPOOL\YourAppPoolName' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
The path of the item '/DemoReport/' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply.

Question:

How can I ensure that the application has the necessary permissions to access the reports using ReportViewer?
What steps should I take to avoid the rsInvalidItemPath error when setting the report path?
Are there any specific configurations required on the server to successfully render and download the merged PDFs using ReportViewer?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


For permission issues, you need to set the identity type of the IIS application pool according to the identity permissions configured in your reporting service. Just refer to this similar case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986419/apppool-permission-issue-with-accessing-report-server
