# Service not firing event when installed on another machine

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created one windows service using C#.
All is working fine. I have tested it on my machine. I have used Timer that fired after every one minute. all are working fine on my machine
 but when I have installed it on another two machines to test its not working. its not firing event after 1 minute.

What could be issue ?

Comment: Well, what kind of timer? I think it's uneasy that the problem is in the timer itself (if the service is running without errors). The problem **may be** in the code you execute when the even is fired. Log log log...

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on the machine that's failing with a higher privilege: Log on as Local System Account.  That should allow you to test whether this is a permissions issue.  If you're setting up logging at the start of your service's launch, you may be failing out because of lack of access to the event logs you expect to write to.

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/510225

Comment: its resolved now. I have checked in log and it was Dll not registered issue on other machine.....