# Why ASP.NET MVC app can play music on its host only if AppPool identity is LocalSystem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool, audio-player

I've hacked up an ASP.NET MVC app which triggers audio playback on its host using WMPLib (COM lib for interactions with Windows Media Player). It works OK when I run it at IIS Express, but at real IIS I hear the music only if AppPool identity is set to LocalSystem. Why exactly is this happened?

Comment: Local system account has more privileges than the Network service. The Local system account has no password (any password information you provide is ignored), has extensive privileges on the local computer
and presents the computer's credentials to remote servers. Should be avoided if possible. For more, see =>  http://stackoverflow.com/a/510225/325521

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, WMPLib is a service (more precisely, a component service). All service run under a local account. More informations can be found in the Component Services Management Console (comexp.msc).
[image: Windows Media Player Component Service]

As we see for this component service, only the interactive user can interact with. The network service will not be able to access it.