# What is the conceptual model regarding accounts in windows nt?

Tags: security, terminology, sid, principal, windows-nt

Are "user *name*" and "user *account*" interchangeable, if yes, to what extent? What about displayed name and eg. [client name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? How local users vs. domain users come into play? What about services like `LocalService`, `LocalSystem` and `NetworkService`? (difference between the latter in [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/)).

All the different ways an actor could access some level of control over an nt system?

Motivation: I'm interested in this so I can find the right functions to retrieve names from a service. Additionally from a security stand-point one would want to be clear.

What is the conceptual model related to accounts in windows nt?

Comment: The "real" immutable name of an NT user account is its [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier).  The user name is just a string associated with the user account, and it can be changed.  The built-in accounts are just accounts.  They have [well known SIDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330).

Comment: @arx: thanks! I added the `principal` tag. so are there different kind of security principals, "just accounts" being different from an "*user* account"? still checking out your links.

Comment: I wasn't intending to make a distinction between "accounts" and "user accounts".  There are other kinds of security principals though.  For example, computers in a domain or logon sessions (which get a temporary SID for the life of the session).  SIDs are also used to implement integrity levels.

Answer (score 0):

A user account has many more properties than just its name. Obviously, a password, but also specific privileges. _Not_part of the account are the rights to specific files; those are associated with the file not the account. Still, those right do refer to accounts

Your "client name" link points to Windows Terminal Services, and it also has a "client build" number. I don't know about your users, but ours are made 100% organic.

The "service" accounts aren't associated with humans, but they do group specific privileges and Access Control Lists may name them.