# How to choose acount name when installing Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

in this mission :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mcLt.jpg)

it's want me to choose account name from list. what is the difference between this accounts name ?

```
NT Authority\system
NT Authority\network service
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco)

Comment: Ideally I would create `Service Accounts` for each of the SQL Server services you will be installing.