# Jenkins Windows slave: Authentication failed if running as service

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, build-agent

I have a Jenkins slave running on Windows 10 (1607). If I run the slave direct as JNLP this slave can clone from the git repository (authentification with username and password).

If I start the same slave as a service, git clone fails with `Authentication failed for ...`.

The service is created over the "File" menu of the slave and is running as "Local System Account".

What's going wrong?

Here is the output from Jenins:

```
00:00:00.003 Started by user <commit-user>
00:00:00.005 ln -s builds/lastSuccessfulBuild /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Xamarin/jobs/MyProject/jobs/CIBuild/lastSuccessful failed: 95 Not supported
00:00:00.005 ln -s builds/lastStableBuild /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Xamarin/jobs/MyProject/jobs/CIBuild/lastStable failed: 95 Not supported
00:00:00.005 Building remotely on Win10Xamarin (Win10 Xamarin Git NetCore) in workspace c:\Jenkins\workspace\Xamarin\iRec Common\iRecy Common CI
00:00:00.025 Cloning the remote Git repository
00:00:00.031 Cloning repository http://git-server/MyGroup/test-project
00:00:00.032  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init c:\Jenkins\workspace\Xamarin\iRec Common\iRecy Common CI # timeout=10
00:00:00.252 Fetching upstream changes from http://git-server/MyGroup/test-project
00:00:00.255  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
00:00:00.351  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://git-server/MyGroup/test-project +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
00:00:01.148 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
00:00:01.149 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://git-server/MyGroup/test-project +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
00:00:01.149 stdout: 
00:00:01.149 stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git-server/MyGroup/test-project/'
00:00:01.149 
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1740)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1476)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:506)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
00:00:01.149    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
00:00:01.149    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
00:00:01.149    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
00:00:01.149    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
00:00:01.149    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
00:00:01.149    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
00:00:01.150    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
00:00:01.150    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
00:00:01.150    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:85)
00:00:01.150    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
00:00:01.150    at ......remote call to Win10Xamarin(Native Method)
00:00:01.150    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
00:00:01.150    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
00:00:01.150    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
00:00:01.150    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
00:00:01.150    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:00:01.150    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:00:01.150    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:00:01.150    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:00:01.153    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
00:00:01.153    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.execute(Unknown Source)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1046)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
00:00:01.153    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
00:00:01.153    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
00:00:01.153 ERROR: null
00:00:01.153 Skipped archiving because build is not successful
00:00:01.154 Recording NUnit tests results
00:00:01.160 FATAL: No NUnit test report files were found. Configuration error?
00:00:01.165 Build step 'Publish NUnit test result report' marked build as failure
00:00:01.180 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how your service is started: if it uses the [Local System account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510225/6309), it would not have the same `%USERPROFILE%` and would not benefit from the same git configuration (usually stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`)

I usually create my service using a user account:

```
sc create JenkinsSlave binPath= d:\Jenkins_Slave\jenkins-slave.exe DisplayName= "Jenkins Slave xxx for https://<url>/jenkins" start= auto obj= DOMAIN\aUSER password= <password>
```

Note the space after `obj=` and `password=`.

Note that is was not working with a Local System account because of a Windows Credential issue, as illustrated in [`JENKINS-34082`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34082?focusedCommentId=253821&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-253821).

> I uninstalled "git" in windows slave machine and the install without using "Windows credential manager".

The [OP WeDucer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271756/webducer) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383890/jenkins-windows-slave-authentication-failed-if-running-as-service#comment66101523_39384474):

> Works: The installed credential manager prevented Local System Account from clone.

Comment: It works, if I change from Local System Account to a specific user. But I not understand why. The specific user have also no .gitconfig and credeantials are passed from Jenkins in both cases.

Comment: @WebDucer Are the url in https or ssh? I see: https. Jenkins must use the credentials associated with the user running the job. In your Jenkins, there must be a credential stored for that user, but there won't be a credential for "Local System Account"

Comment: I use http. The user the service is runnig with is different from user stored in credential store. (e.g: service user is "build-agent" and git user is "gitAgent").

Comment: @WebDucer Do you mean `gitAgent` is not in the Jenkins Credential Store? Then Git (on the slave) must use a credential helper (do, as `gitAgent`, a `git config -l` to see if that is the case)

Comment: No. I mean the slave service run with some user and Jenkins (server) has gitAgent in the credential store. Local on the slave machine git credential helper is not set.

Comment: @WebDucer Maybe git is using the Windows credential manager? (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34082?focusedCommentId=253821&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-253821)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try the solution. Sound like mine.

Comment: Works. The installed credential manager prevented Local System Account from clone.

Comment: @WebDucer Well done. I have included your comment and the Jenkins issue in the answer for more visibility.