# How can I change the user on Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash

[image]

I want to sign out an actual user so I can sign in with another user.

What I see in Git bash is:

```
MINGW64 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ConstructorJava (master)
git push -u origin/master
remote: Permission to Fre1234/ConstructorJava.git denied to Fre123.  
Fatal: unable to access https://github.com/Fre1234/ConstructorJava.git/": The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Check what `git remote -v` returns: the account used to push to an http url is usually embedded into the remote url itself.

```
https://Fre123@github.com/...
```

If that is the case, put an url which will force Git to ask for the account to use when pushing:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

Or one to use the Fre1234 account:

```
git remote set-url origin https://Fre1234@github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

Also check if you installed your [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) with or without a credential helper [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384474/6309).

---

The [OP Fre1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815751/fre1234) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422521/how-can-i-change-the-user-on-git-bash/39462517#comment67926600_39462517):

> I finally found the solution.
>   Go to: `Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials -> Windows Credentials`
>
> Under `Generic Credentials` there are some credentials related to Github,
>   Click on them and click "`Remove`".

That is because the default installation for [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) set a [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).
See `git config --global credential.helper` output (it should be `manager`)

Comment: Thank you because of it, I finally  found the solution. Go to: Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials -> Windows Credentials -> under Generic Credentials there are some credentials related to Github, click on them and click "Remove".

Comment: @Fre1234 Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: HI vonC , Thank's for adding comment. it worked for me too. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Well, the credential manager is the way; the original answer will not work, in case when my username is a email address, I then have two `@` in the URL. However, what if we can change in credential manager, so that it contains different `username` and `password`. Now the username  is `PersonalToken`.

Comment: @WesternGun Regarding the @, would https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172831/6309 help?

Answer (score 13):

**For any OS**

This helped me so I'll put it here, just in case.
Once you are done with adding the rsa keys for both the accounts, add a config file in your `.ssh` directory for both the accounts (`.ssh/config`)

```
# First account
Host github.com-<FIRST_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE>
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1
   
# Second account
Host github.com-<SECOND_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE>   
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

Make sure you use the correct usernames and RSA files. Next, you can open the terminal/git bash on the repository root and check which account you would be pushing from

```
git config user.email
```

Suppose this returns the first user email and you want to push from the second user. Change the local `user.name` and `user.email` :

```
git config user.name "SECOND_USER"
git config user.email "SECOND_USER@example.com"
```

(This won't change the global config and you can have the first user set up as the global user). Once done, you can confirm with `git config user.email` and it should return the email of the second user. You're all set to push to GitHub with the second user. The rest is all the same old `git add` , `git commit` and `git push`.
To push from the first user, change the local `user.name` again and follow the same steps.
Hope it helps :)

---

If the above steps are still not working for you, check to see if you have uploaded the RSA keys within GitHub portal. [Refer to GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account):

Then, clear your ssh cached keys [Reference](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)

```
ssh-add -D
```

Then add you 2 ssh keys

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

Then type in your terminal:

```
ssh -T git@github.com-<SECOND_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE>
```

You should see the following output:

```
Hi <SECOND_USERNAME>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Then, assign the correct remote to your local repository. Make sure you put the same username as the one you gave in your `.ssh/config` file next to `Host`. In the following case `git@github.com-<SECOND_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE>`.

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com-<SECOND_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE>:/your_username/your_repository.git
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**For Mac Users**

I am using Mac and I was facing same problem while I was trying to push a project from Android Studio. The reason for that other user had previously logged into Github and his credentials were saved in Keychain Access.

You need to remove those credentials from Keychain Access and then try to push.

Hope it help to Mac users.

Answer (score 4):

**For Mac Users**

I am using Mac and I was facing the same problem while I was trying to push a project from Android Studio. The reason for that is another user had previously logged into GitHub and his credentials were saved in Keychain Access.

The solution is to delete all the information store in keychain for that process

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the user at git Bash .You just need to configure particular user and email(globally) at the git bash.

```
$ git config --global user.name "abhi"
$ git config --global user.email "abhi@xyz.com"
```

Note: No need to delete the user from Keychain .

Answer (score 2):

### **WINDOWS**

Looks like there are already plenty of solutions here but I thought I'd share mine anyway, which is a spin on this from [Vonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc):

> The OP Fre1234 adds in the comments:
>
> > I finally found the solution. Go to: Control Panel -> User Accounts ->
> > Manage your credentials -> Windows Credentials
> >
> > Under Generic Credentials there are some credentials related to
> > Github, Click on them and click "Remove".

Instead of deleting the credential for the first account, I just created a new PAT on GitHub for the second account, and clicked on `Add a generic credential`.

[image: Generic credential button]

Then filled it out like this:

[image: GitHub account details]

I don't know exactly what permissions it needs, so I just used these:

[image: PAT Permissions]

I can now clone and push with no problems, but **MAKE SURE TO CHANGE YOUR EMAIL TO THE ONE YOU USE FOR THE SECOND ACCOUNT**. Otherwise, it will look like your commits were made with your first account.

```
$ git config --global user.email "SECONDACCOUNT@EMAIL.COM"
```

I personally don't bother changing `user.name`, from my little experimenting it seems GitHub uses the email to fetch the username and avatar anyway, and only uses the name if the email is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution, if you want to switch accounts to use git commands like push with another account in Windows CLI:

```
$ git config credential.username 'YourUserName'
```

Make sure your user.name and user.email are equals to your credential.username doing:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Nanhe Kumar"
$ git config --global user.email "info@nanhekumar.com"
```

Comment: As far as I know, `user.name`/`email` settings are only used for local commit authorship, not for remote authentication.