# git push - Permission to denied - The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

As many other, when I use git push I get the next error:

remote: Permission to mmistakes/minimal-mistakes.git denied to MyName.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I´m working in Windows, I have git 2.22.
I tried:

1. Running the following two commands in the terminal, replacing the obvious things:

git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email "Your Email Address Here"

2. This one "[How can I change the user on Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422521/how-can-i-change-the-user-on-git-bash)"
3. Deleting the Windows Credential
4. Adding a ssh keys to Github

But non of those things work for me.

Comment: .ssh keys are irrelevant if you're accessing over HTTPS. Use the `git@github.com` URL if you want to use SSH.

Comment: Are you using your username and password to push, or are you using a token? Do you have two-factor authentication set up?

Answer (score 1):

403 is a forbidden error code... so as long as you are sure your git user name and password are accurate, you then must make sure you are an authorized user on the GitHub repo check [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository) for more details on what permission you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are `mmistakes` on GitHub, you won't be able to push directly to this repository, unless `mmistakes` [declares you as a collaborator](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository).

Consider [forking `mmistakes/minimal-mistakes.git`](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo), and you will be able to push back (HTTPS or SSH) to said forked repository.