# How do I push to github?

Tags: git, github

remote: Permission to cs100/template-lab-01-intro-to-sct-unit-testing.git denied to barbosa42.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cs100/template-lab-01-intro-to-sct-unit-testing.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: You're trying to push to the upstream, by the looks of it; you can't push your code to other people's repos unless they make you a collaborator. You should probably make a fork (see e.g. https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git push - Permission to denied - The requested URL returned error: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719727/git-push-permission-to-denied-the-requested-url-returned-error-403)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403

Answer (score 1):

403 is an [HTTP response code for Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). Very likely you don't have permissions to write/push (only pull/clone) in the git repository

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have internet access on your device & you are using proper credentials.