# Could not access schtasks(Task Scheduler) when the service is running as local system account

Tags: windows, operating-system, system-administration

I read that Local system Account has maximum privileges to access all the local resources.
But still I could not create a scheduler task while running my application as a service.
When I run my application as administrator(cmd),I was able to create a scheduler task

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 20 /tn "Tesk Check" /tr "C:\run.bat"
```

When I run this command as a service,I got this error

> No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Did I miss anything?

Comment: The local system account doesn't have all the infrastructure associated with a real account, so some functionality isn't available ... but in this particular case, it works fine for me, both on Windows 7, 8.1, and 10.  I was using `psexec` to run the command in the context of a service, as local system.

Comment: I suggest you try using `psexec` and see if that works for you; if it does, there might be an issue with the configuration of your service.  As a last resort, you might even be able to work around the problem by calling `psexec` *from* your service to run `schtasks`. :-)

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston. PsExec works fine.I may need to find any configuration mistake in my service

Comment: Try running `whoami /all` both via `psexec` and via your service and compare the results.

Comment: from result I can see that,PsExec runs the command as "Admin" user and My service runs the command as "nt authority\system".
Here is the output:
https://play.golang.org/p/6y5kWKLD-X

Comment: D'oh!  Sorry, I should have explained: you need to use the `-s` flag to `psexec` if you want it to run the command as local system.  Does it still work with `-s` ?

Comment: Hi @HarryJohnston,If I run Psexec with "-s" ,It could not add task to schtasks.Hence Only Admin user can access schtasks ;)

Comment: That's puzzling, because it works for me.  Perhaps your security software is interfering?  Or there is some other difference between our systems; I'm in a Active Directory domain, and that could make a difference I guess.

Comment: Local system Account have all the privileges in "Active Directory".
ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco
I am not in a Active Directory.So I have to run my service as Admin I guess