# Running Jenkins from command line vs as Windows service

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, proxy

I ran into a very strange issue. I need to configure proxy in my Jenkins to be able to access SVN repository in one of the jobs. I have done so in 2 ways:

1. Started Jenkins from command line with the required arguments
2. Started Jenkins as Windows service while the arguments are defined in the `jenkins.xml` file.

**Starting from command line**:

> ```
> C:\>java -DJENKINS_HOME="C:\.jenkins" -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP
> ="`script-src 'unsafe-inline';`" -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=312
> 8 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -jar %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins
> .war
> ```

**Starting as service (below is the jenkins.xml contents)**:

```
<executable>java</executable>
<arguments>-DJENKINS_HOME="C:\.jenkins" -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="`script-src 'unsafe-inline';`" -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -jar "%JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins.war"</arguments>
```

So that's exactly the same. The issue however is that when I am using command line to start Jenkins, proxying works fine. But when I start Jenkins as service, the repo (through the proxy) cannot be accessed and I get this error message:

[image: unable to access repository error]

Please note that if I look at the System Properties in System Information section, the proxy parameters appear the same in both cases so the configuration is being applied properly:

[image: System Properties]

Apparently there is a difference in how Jenkins starts up depending on how it was started (command line or windows service). What reinforces this assumption is that I see that some log files are only being written when I start Jenkins as a service but not when I start it from command line. I am talking about these log files:

```
jenkins.wrapper.log
jenkins.out.log
```

What do I need to do differently to get the same result from Jenkins as service as I do when I start it from command line? What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Which user runs the Jenkins service? It's _LocalSystem_ by default. See the answer to [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510225/1744774) for the implications.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Hi and thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction. I studied the linked question and it helped me to find a way to configure the service to run using my current user account instead of the default LocalSystem. Please post a full answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins as a Windows service doesn't run under your current user but under the [LocalSystem Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) by default.

See [MSDN: Using the LocalSystem Account as a Service Logon Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677973(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SO: The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco/510225#510225) for the implications.