# Ldap - the network path was not found

Tags: c#, ldap

I encountered below error when trying to search users in LDAP.

The code runs ok at local PC and error occurs only at windows server after I deployed it.

> 2018-08-17 15:29:21.190 +08:00 [Error] Error in getting fullname for lsun
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80070035): The network path was not found.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
>   at Company.Project.Common.Utility.LDAPUtility.QueryLDAPUserFullName(String userId) in C:\Code\Project\branches\test\src\DotNet\Company.Project.Common\Utility\LDAPUtility.cs:line 344
>   at Company.Project.Common.Utility.LDAPUtility.GetUserFullName(String userId) in C:\Code\Project\branches\test\src\DotNet\Company.Project.Common\Utility\LDAPUtility.cs:line 239

This is a Windows service application and this is the code throwing the error:

```
private static string QueryLDAPUserFullName(string userId)
{
    string fullName = "";

    DirectoryEntry objDirEnt = new DirectoryEntry(ConstPrivileges.ADSPROVIDER + "://" + ConstPrivileges.DOMAIN + "/" + userId);

    if (objDirEnt.Children != null)
        fullName = objDirEnt.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();//Line 344

    return fullName;
}
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful yes it's sAMAccountName. If I don't append userId, how does it know which user i'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing the windows service logon from 'Local Service' to 'Network Service'. It seems to me that Local Service does not have privilege to connect to LDAP.

[The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco)